# Triangle one angle and two lengths

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle ABC, the angle at B is 108 degrees, the length of side BC is 16, and the length of side AB is 12.  To 2 decimal places, what is the length of side AC?

So i worked out and out and got this answer
 22.77 is that right? I used cosine rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using cosine rule, $AC^2=16^2+12^2-2(16)(12)\cos 108^\circ$, so you are right.